# Mysql timestamp on update attribute linked to another column

Tags: mysql

I have table worktickets:

I would like attribute `updated_1` to update with timestamp when `follow_up1` is updated.

```
wt_id      follow_up1         updated_1            follow_up2        updated_2
1              red            2017-08-24 09:50
```

However, when `follow_up2` is updated, the value in `updated_1` should remain the same, and only `updated_2` is updated:

```
wt_id      follow_up1         updated_1            follow_up2        updated_2
1              red            2017-08-24 09:50       blue             2017-08-24 10:50
```

these are both currently set to 'ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', and both `updated_1` and `updated_2` update when either of the follow_up columns are updated. Is there a way to link them so they only update when another attribute is updated?

Answer (score 0):

The only way you could do this on database side would be with a trigger, but I would recommend to have this logic in your application code, not in the database. Simply because of keeping things clean. Application logic should stay in the application.

If you insist, though, you could do it with

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER mytriggername BEFORE UPDATE ON mytablename
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (OLD.follow_up1 <> NEW.follow_up1) THEN
SET NEW.updated_1 = NOW();
END IF;
/* and so on, same for the other column */
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```